# Same HTTP.post on client and on server give different results in Meteor

Tags: http, meteor, oauth, http-error, http-status-code-400

I'm doing an OAuth with `grant_type` set to `password` (which means, I can do this client-only). The code is as simple as

```
HTTP.post(`${api}/token`, {
  params: {
    grant_type: 'password',
    client_id: 'some_id',
    client_sectet: 'some_secret',
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password'
  }
}, (e, r) => {
  if (e) {
    console.error(e);
  } else {
    console.log(r);
  }
});
```

In the `meteor shell`. i.e. on the server, the code is executed as it should, and proper data structure with access token is returned by OAuth server, which proves that both server setup, grant type, client credentials and user credentials are valid. But on the client, with exactly the same code, I'm having an error:

```
POST http://.../token 400 (Bad Request)
Error: failed [400] {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"The grant type was not specified in the request"}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is this happening? Is it not possible to do this kind of requests on the client at all?

Comment: What happens when you do console.log(api) before you run the HTTP.post()?

Comment: Everything is clean. Again, the code is shared between client and server and runs perfectly on the server. Is there something that browser adds (headers or something) that makes it fail in the browser?